# Print all net sip before cb_final

Tags: perl, sip

**how i can print all net sip response**

in perl net sip  we use `$ua->register` and we use cb_final call back to get final response

how i can Print all requests and responses before receiving  cb_final call back

I know cb_final is the final result of  `$ua->register`

What I need are the operations shown in debug, but as printing without using debug

Answer (score 1):

> What I need are the operations shown in debug, but as printing without using debug

There is no mechanism for this in Net::SIP. And "what I need" does not really describe the use case, why such a mechanism should be added.

Comment: What I mean sir is that I need to print a response in every loop. Not only when cb_final is finished

Comment: Where there are things like WWW-Authenticate I can't print it

Comment: @somavasamco: *"... that I need ..."* - this still only says *that* you need it not *why*. See also [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm not good at English. B Please help me solve the problem instead of checking the writing method

Comment: how i can print WWW-Authenticate in sip request $ua->register

Comment: @somavasamco: again - there is no built-in way and it is still not clear why debug output is not sufficient for this.

Comment: I am doing a university graduation project for sip protection
And I need to extract realm and WWW-Authenticate data
To be used in the program's output

Comment: @somavasamco: don't provide any authentication information. Then you should get a failure back in `cb_final`.  `$args{packet}` in this callback contains the response packet from the server which also include the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Comment: i use Data::Dumper; to print( Dumper($args{packet})); it is not found  but i see it in debug

Comment: @somavasamco: please provide what exactly you get in cb_final, i.e. what and %args

Comment: i beg u open chat with you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245239/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-somava-samco).